# Add a logo to Master Page Header

Tags: c#, asp.net, header, master-pages

I need to add a logo to my master page header.
like this image.

https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&hs=755&biw=1326&bih=631&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=injIWq73DoLM0gTz77D4Aw&q=master+page+headers+logo+asp.net&oq=master+page+headers+logo+asp.net&gs_l=psy-ab.3...5276.6757.0.6809.8.8.0.0.0.0.306.915.0j2j1j1.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..4.0.0....0.Xala6Vu6ROk#imgrc=Vf6q-HefqKohMM:

could anyone help me with this.

Comment: Have you looked at css to style your webpage?

Comment: Just create an empty project using the default template and the answer will be staring at you (it's done for you).